# Vectorize code and remove nested loops from pytorch code

Tags: pytorch, image-segmentation, torch, semantic-segmentation

[image: code]

Is it possible to remove the nested loop for iterating over all images and then row-wise iteration over all pixels of these images? I am finding it difficult because I need to use the location of the pixel(h,w)  from another variable label to choose exactly which channel's h, w value needs to be zeroed.

[Colab Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QbC--rgNFDq6llLpMi6wI_6ley69Zb35?usp=sharing)

Overall what I need to do is given output of segmentation ([2,2,2,2]) (n, channels, height, width), and corresponding labels([2,2,2]) (n,height,width). I need to add another tensor M same size as output, which has a constant value m at all channels except the ground truth channel(from labels) for all the pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize this. Recognize that `n`, `h`, and `w` correspond to all pixel values of both `m` and `labels`. As a result, you can do the following:

```py
m[:, labels, ...] = 0
```

Comment: I tried using this but maybe my interpretation was wrong, what exactly should it be 'm[:, labels, :,  :,] = 0' , this makes everything zero.

Answer (score 0):

Got it the answer that I found was using torch.Tensor.scatter_()

```
new_labels = torch.unsqueeze(labels, 1)
m.scatter_(dim=1, index=new_labels, src=torch.zeros( 2, 2, 2, 2))
```

basically, first make the shape of labels to the M shape and then add zeros to m at the locations specified by the labels by choosing the axis.